# Restore of database doesn't show content

Tags: database

I had to reset and reinstall wordpress bescause of compatibility issues between some plug-ins. So as usual, I took a full back-up of the website, databse, home directory, email, etc....
After a new clean wordpress install, I selected my backed-up databse, so wordpress won't create a new one, but even so, all the content and post, pages, images are not showing up in the wordpress dashboard. If I check the database in C Panel with my PHP admin, it shows everything, all the post and pages. But why the hell aren't they showing in my dashboard ?
Some help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you are actually using the database by doing the following:

1 - go to cpanel, file manager, public_html, open the wp_config.php file

2 - check db creds and make sure it is actually the correct db. Everything must be exact. (IP/localhost, dbname, user, etc.)

3 - check the $table_prefix - make sure the value matches the table that holds the post/pages. (Wordpress uses $table_prefix so you can actually have multiple wordpress installs in the same database.)
E.g. $table_prefix = 'wp_';  but your actual table name for posts is `site_posts` - then that's the problem, they are different sites. If your actual table name is `wp_posts` - then it is OK.

4 - check your users table. Does the users match what you see in admin panel? If not, the website is not stored in that database.

Let's say the prefix or any of the creds is wrong - just fix it directly in wp_config.php by editing the value to match. It should work right away.

Comment: First, thank you for taking the time answer, the strategy was rather complex, but :) after reading it about 7 times and carefully putting it into action, it did actually work. Thanks again.